# Windows 10 + The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, visual-studio-2012, windows-10, tls1.2

He there,

I am getting below errors...

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

I am trying to call third party API.. that is working in Windows 7 but after i upgrade to Windows 10 it fails...

I have also tried changing Security Protocol using coding below

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

I have also tried some registry edit like below..

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 
Value: SchUseStrongCrypto
```

Another strange issue is that it is connected in alternate fashion...
First time it connects but abort consecutive request..

Please any one can help me solving this issue

Note: Problem comes after i update Windows 10 from Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a web service with SHA1 encryption.  A windows update will block it as its risky.

The following link lists the updates.
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/04/29/sha1-deprecation-roadmap/

Uninstall the update/s and it should work.  It did for me.
However you should look into getting that web service upgraded.

I have as of yet to figure out a way around the issue programmatically.